# working shell command fails to execute with scala.sys.process

Tags: scala, shell

Following command executes successfully when ran in a shell

```
csvsql --db "postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/samples" --table sample_table --insert /absolute.path.csv
```

but fails to execute when ran from scala like this:

```
s"""csvsql --db "postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/samples" --table sample_table --insert /absolute.path.csv""" !!
```

with following error:

ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '"postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/samples"'

Comment: Try changing the double quotes inside the string to single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell will have removed the quotes before passing the argument to the process, so you need to remove the quotes from the db string. It is probably better to use a `Seq` of arguments rather than a string:

```
Seq("csvsql", "--db", "postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/samples", "--table", "sample_table", "--insert", "/absolute.path.csv") !!
```